# Increase Timeout for specific its-Method of cypress.io

Tags: cypress

With cypress.io get-Method we can define a timeout only valid for this specific get-method call:

```
cy.get('.mobile-nav', { timeout: 10000 })
```

Is there a way to define a timeout for a specific its-method call like:

```
cy.window().its('MyClass')
```

Or do I need to increase defaultCommandTimeout in cypress.json?

Comment: The `its` command does not accept any arguments other than `propertyName`. If called with more than that, it bails with an error: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/0f73bb7e1910296469f3f631a7f2303f4ecd035e/packages/driver/src/cy/commands/connectors.coffee#L169

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Place this in the its block before you want it used:

```
Cypress.config('defaultCommandTimeout', 10000);
```

[Cypress.config() documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/config.html#Syntax)

Comment: of course, I might need to change back the defaultCommandTimeout after calling the its-Method

Comment: [The docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/config#Not-all-config-values-can-be-changed-at-all-times) say timeouts cannot be configured at run-time. 

"Anything that's not directly under Cypress's control - like timeouts, userAgent, or environment variables - will be ignored at run-time."

Comment: @AleksanderRyhlitski Doc has been updated, `defaultCommandTimeout` can be changed at runtime.

Answer (score 33):

I'd prefer to set timeout for a specific test instead of modifying global config.

```
it('should do something', {
  defaultCommandTimeout: 10000
}, () => {
  // ...
})
```

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/writing-and-organizing-tests.html#Allowed-config-values

Comment: Correct link to config options: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Timeouts

Comment: Maybe you don't prefer it but you should still include how to modify the global config as well

Answer (score 17):

For me, I just do this wherever I wanted to wait

```
cy.get('ELEMENT', {timeout:50000})
```

Comment: The `get` accepting exactly this was explicitly mentioned in the question; and was not what was asked here.

Answer (score 4):

Based on [Joel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59205575/2398593), here's what I did to restore to the default timeout right after:

```
const DEFAULT_COMMAND_TIMEOUT = Cypress.config().defaultCommandTimeout;

// there's no easy way to increase the timeout when using
// `its` command therefore we need to save the current
// timeout, change it globally, and restore it after
Cypress.config('defaultCommandTimeout', 15000);

return cy
  .window()
  .its('something')
  .should('exist')
  .then(() => {
    Cypress.config('defaultCommandTimeout', DEFAULT_COMMAND_TIMEOUT);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

My web app was launching over 6 XHR (*which is over the default limit of chrome*) requests upon login, so request I am intercepting occasionally takes more than default `5000`

`Cypress.config('requestTimeout', 10000);`

Answer (score -1):

Instead of specifying this in individual tests I updated my `cypress.json` with the following...

```json
{
 "defaultCommandTimeout": 10000
}
```

Answer (score -3):

It seems that this should work (not tested it though):

```js
cy.window().its({ timeout: 10000 }, 'MyClass')
```

Comment: does not seem to work: "CypressError: cy.its() only accepts a string as the first argument."